# Does Devise supports deferent models for deferent roles? (in rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use Devise in my new project,but I have some problems in roles.

There are two kinds of user in my project,but these two kinds of user have deferent data structure(very different).

I Know Devise supports roles,but how should I deal with the deferent user data structure?

Thank you.

Comment: Devise is an authentication solution. If you're talking roles, you're talking about authorization. Try CanCan for defining roles on different types of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise documentation states that you can have as many Roles with different models as you want ([configuring multiple models](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/file/README.rdoc#Configuring_multiple_models))

You just set up the other model as you did with the first one and then add to `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :admins
```

And then you can use inside your controllers and views:

```
# Inside your protected controller
before_filter :authenticate_admin!

# Inside your controllers and views
admin_signed_in?
current_admin
admin_session
```

The main question is how to let both of these accounts access the same controller (if it is applicable to your case), because of the two `before_filters` the first would always redirect to login page, if that is not the logged-in role (say :admin). You would probably have to implement a custom before_filter to validate the session against two roles simultaneously.

You could probably work around this with custom routes for these roles. E.g `/admin/projects` and `/user/projects`. In that case the [`authenticate`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticate-instance_method) method could be helpful.